# WordPress и своя верстка

Tags: wordpress

Вот не могу понять, как найти информацию по тому, как правильно натягивать свою верстку, чтобы можно было менять все в админке/настройка темы. Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если несложно, дайте ссылки на информацию, как это реализовать без плагинов.

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/10/visible-edit-shortcuts-in-the-customizer-preview/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/tools-for-improved-user-experience/#selective-refresh-fast-accurate-updates

Comment: Правильно (особенно для тех, кто ВП слабо занает) - не "натягивать", а делать [дочернюю тему](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) к темам из [репо](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

То, что вы показали на картинке, называется Theme Customizer. Туда можно добавить свою секцию, а в нее - нужные опции.

Например, создадим секцию "Контакты для всего сайта" и добавим два телефона и почту. Для этого надо добавить нижеприведенный код в functions.php:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function ( $customizer ) {
    global $global_email;

    $customizer->add_section(
        'section_contacts',
        array(
            'title'       => 'Контакты для всего сайта',
            'description' => 'Контактная информация для страниц сайта',
            'priority'    => 20,
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_setting(
        'section_contacts_moscow_phone',
        array(
            'default' => '+7 (499) 322-33-22',
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_control(
        'section_contacts_moscow_phone',
        array(
            'label'   => 'Московский телефон',
            'section' => 'section_contacts',
            'type'    => 'text',
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_setting(
        'section_contacts_federal_phone',
        array(
            'default' => '8 (800) 322-33-22',
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_control(
        'section_contacts_federal_phone',
        array(
            'label'   => 'Федеральный телефон',
            'section' => 'section_contacts',
            'type'    => 'text',
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_setting(
        'section_contacts_email',
        array(
            'default' => 'info@mysite.ru',
        )
    );
    $customizer->add_control(
        'section_contacts_email',
        array(
            'label'   => 'Email',
            'section' => 'section_contacts',
            'type'    => 'text',
        )
    );
} );
```

Использование:

```
$current_phone = get_theme_mod( 'section_contacts_moscow_phone', '' );
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полезные ссылки на документацию по теме (из комментариев @HamSter и @SeVlad)

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/tools-for-improved-user-experience/#selective-refresh-fast-accurate-updates
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/10/visible-edit-shortcuts-in-the-customizer-preview/

Comment: ок спасибо за ответ очень благодарен за информацию!
можно еще уточнить как в саму верстку вставлять?

Comment: Я добавлю ссылку на ман: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Comment: О, не увидел ;) она и др полезная ссылка в комменте к вопросу есть.

Comment: да, совершенно правильный вопрос, забыл. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @HamSter да этим тоже можно. Я смотрю в код twentyseventeen, они там в файле /inc/customizer.php задают карандашики с помощью selector и render_callback

Comment: @KAGGDesign, точно, извините, не досмотрела. Спасибо!!

Comment: @HamSter нет проблем ))