# Натянуть верстку на WordPress с внесением изменений через админку

Tags: wordpress

Есть верстка со слайдерами, js-скриптами и всякими наворотами...1600 строк +-.

Нужно это все прописать в теме. В данном случае, это одна страница и верстка вставляется в файл home.php. НО! нужно, чтобы каждую строку, каждую картинку можно было бы поменять из админки WordPress. Каким образом это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: Способов много. Можно так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220

Answer (score 0):

Способов много и все зависит от того какой функционал у текста и картинок, которые нужно редактировать.
Если это статичные текст и картинка для главной, то мне нравится пользоваться стандартным вордпресс кaстомайзером.
Всталвяем этот код в файл functions.php и редактируем под свои опции.

```
// main menu - appearance - customize
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    // header section
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'data_site_section_header',
        array(
            "priority" => 10,
            'title' => 'Настройки шапки сайта',
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
            'description' => "Тут можно указать данные сайта"
        )
    );

    // образец ввода изображения
    // logo
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'themeslug_logo' );
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Логотип шапки', 'themeslug' ),
        'section'  => 'data_site_section_header',
        'settings' => 'themeslug_logo',
    ) ) );

    // образец со стандартным инпутом
    // Номер телефона часть 1
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'custom_site_telephone_main_1',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'type' => 'option'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'site_telephone_main_1_control',
        array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => "Номер телефона часть 1",
            'section' => 'data_site_section_header',
            'settings' => 'custom_site_telephone_main_1'
        )
    );
    // образец с текстовым полем
    // Текст в подвале сайта
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'custom_footer_text',
        array(
            'default' => '',
            'type' => 'option'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'footer_text_control',
        array(
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'label' => "Текст в подвале сайта",
            'section' => 'data_site_section_header',
            'settings' => 'custom_footer_text'
        )
    );
}
```

Затем идем в админке Главное меню -> внешний вид -> настроить и вставляем нужные картинки и текст. 
Затем в коде верстки их можно вывести при помщи таких снипетов кода

```
// для текста
echo get_option('custom_site_telephone_main_1');
// для изображений
esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'themeslug_logo' ) );
```