# Есть ли возможность быстрого редактирования ACF полей wp темы?

Tags: wordpress

Использую плагин [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) для вывода произвольных полей в wp темы. WP версия 4.8.

**home.php**:

```
<div class="row features">
  <?php
    query_posts('post_type=services&posts_per_page=-1' );
      if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  ?>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <span class="fa fa-3x fa-<?php if(get_field('fa-')) { echo  get_field('fa-'); } ?>"></span>
      <h4>
        <?php if(get_field('services__title')) { echo  get_field('services__title'); } ?>
      </h4>
      <p>
        <?php if(get_field('services__desc')) { echo  get_field('services__desc'); } ?>
       </p>
     </div>

  <?php 
    endwhile;  
    endif;
    wp_reset_query(); 
   ?>
 </div>
```

**Вопрос:** Есть ли возможность редактировать поля acf из настроек превью темы (и с карандашиками, кликая по которым можно перейти к редактированию)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности нет, да она и не нужна совершенно. То, что вы показали - это стандартный функционал WordPress под названием Theme Customizer, работающий без всяких плагинов. О том, как пользоваться Theme Customizer, смотрите мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220