# Как создать кнопку добавления полей в настройках темы wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

Столкнулся с такой проблемой на WP. Не могу создать функцию под номером 1, чтобы появлялись дополнительные поля(под номером 2) и блоки на сайте( под номером 3, с синими иконками). Функция добавления новых преимуществ в лендинге.
[image: Кнопка добавления нового блока]

Comment: Этот функционал называется Theme Customizer. Посмотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220 там есть пример и ссылки на документацию.

Comment: Нужна кнопка для пользователя, чтобы он сам мог добавить новый блок преимуществ. Он нажал «add an item» появились еще поля с блоком на сайте.