# Не выводится текст через админку Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Добрый день. Прошу помочь мне справиться с проблемой.

Хочу сделать настраиваемый текст через кастомайзер Wordpress.

Кастомайзер настроил, поле ввода отображается, но текст не выводит, и все.

```
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section('themename_color_scheme', array(
    'title'    => __('Текст слева', 'themename'),
    'description' => '',
    'priority' => 120,
));

//  =============================
//  = Text Input                =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[text_test]', array(
    'default'        => 'Введи текст',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));

$wp_customize->add_control('themename_text_test', array(
    'label'      => __('Пытаемся', 'themename'),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'themename_theme_options[text_test]',
));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
```

[image: Место встречи]

```
<?php

            if ( get_theme_mod( 'themename_text_test' ) ) : ?>

            <span> <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'themename_text_test','' ); ?></span>

            <?php 
            else : ?>

            <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Поместите код в вопрос в виде текста, он должен индексироваться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я первый раз на сайте, поэтому пока не знаю, как редактировать вопрос.

Comment: Под текстом вопроса есть ссылка "Править" http://take.ms/fzBZ9

Comment: Ага, не заметил)