# Как сделать, чтобы номер телефона мог меняться через консоль WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="top-nav">
        <? the_custom_logo( $blog_id ); ?>
            <a href="tel:+998903551715" class="tel">+998903551715<i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы номер телефона мог меняться через консоль WordPress.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - использовать customizer: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723273/220220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_settings_field
Там всё найдёте, только поменять параметры

Comment: Спасибо, помогло